# Hibernate logger does not replace %s

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, logback

I noticed for a while now that **hibernate does not replace `%s`** templates in log messages. Our own log message are replaced fine. My project uses spring boot (slf4j + logback included).

Hibernate info at server start looks like this:

[image: hibernate example]

Other libs are affected as well:

[image: xnio example]

Dependency graph, as requested: https://pastebin.com/b0QcBBnV

Comment: Can you do a `mvn help:effective-pom` add the log related dependencies present to question?

Comment: I've added the dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To configure hibernate to use `slf4j`, it need the following property , it need either starting the application with

```
    -Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j
```

or in the Main Spring boot application class

```
    static { 
        System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");
    }
```

**Steps taken to figure out what went on**

This is not actually an answer but some steps to troubleshoot as one of the classes above is `JtaPlatformInitiator` as I can't replicate it.

- Put a breakpoint in the class `JtaPlatformInitiator.org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal` at the following line:

```
    LOG.usingJtaPlatform( platform != null ? platform.getClass().getName() : "null" );
```

- When the application starts, it is going to come to the above line.
- Then it will reach this jboss class and you can see the `unformatted string` as well as `params`.
  [image]
- Now once you go inside this method, it should be choosing one of them and prepare one `formatted string`. For me, it went to `org.jboss.logging.Log4j2Logger` and is concatenating correctly.

  [image]
- Can you check what class selected for you in the last step?

Comment: I have the same classes to choose from, but for me, it went to "JBossLogManagerLogger".

Comment: Did you try going further into that class because it is still not concatenating but delegating further so you can see where concatenation of string and params happen

Comment: I traced it back to `org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler#getMessageI18N` method, which completely ignores the `LogRecord`s property `formatStyle=PRINTF` is set. (Params are there, so it should be able to do the templating.)

Comment: I just checked that method too and I get your point about it ignoring the format. Unfortunately I have no idea. I will dig in when I get sometime

Comment: Thank you! My gut feeling is, that it has to do something with the jboss logger. The problem seems only be present in jboss related deps: hibernate, netty, undertow.

Comment: I might have got bit further into this. Can you try starting your application with the following options one by one? 1)  `-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=log4j2` 2)`-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j`  If any of them work, then it actually how to exclude `JBossLogManagerProvider`